# Remove borders from bars in histogram in R

Tags: r

How can I remove the borders around bars in R, so that only the fill remains?

Instead of this:

[image]

I want this:

[image]

## I do *not* want to color the borders!

Comment: I'm curious - how did you remove the borders for the second example in your post?

Comment: @jbaums Photoshop ;-)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can set this parameter as an extra option for `hist`, as `lty="blank"`:

```
hist(rnorm(100), lty="blank", col="hotpink")
```

Comment: what does `lty` stand for?

Comment: I believe it is an abbreviation of 'linetype'.